# Filtering a pair of arrays for a certain range of numbers using python

Tags: python, arrays, filtering

So let's say I have two arrays x and y.

`x = [5, -6, 3, 11, -4, 2]`
`y = [1, 9, 2, 8, 12, -5]`

I need to filter these arrays, keeping only values between 0 and 10.  I was able to do this separately:

`new_x=[i for i in x if i>=0 and i<=10]` with output
`[5, 3, 2]`

`new_y=[i for i in y if i>=0 and i<=10]` with output
`[1, 9, 2, 8]`

However, these x and y arrays are meant to symbolize coordinates, which I will later have to graph.  They have to remain in pairs, so if an element in the x array does not fulfill the criteria, I do not want to include the matching y element.  Same goes vice versa.

By looking at the arrays, it is easy to tell that only the first and third pair - (5,1) and (3,2) respectively - fulfill my criteria.   How can I filter x and y together to represent this?  My dataset is much larger than this example, so I do not have the time to filter through it manually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip` them together:

```
pairs = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(x, y) if 0 <= a <= 10 and 0 <= b <= 10]
# [(5, 1), (3, 2)]
```

If you then want to go back to `x`, `y` (I wouldn't recommend this, just keep them together), you could use:

```
x, y = zip(*pairs)
```

Which will return `x` and `y` as tuples:

```
x = (5, 3)
y = (1, 2)
```

In this context, the two tuples look like ordered pairs, but in general you could get something like

```
x = (5, 3, -6, 11, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much for the help!  This was exactly what I was looking for and worked perfectly!

Comment: Hi @codinggirl17 , if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thank you - I would have accepted it earlier, but I didn't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` function

```py
filtered_coords = list(
    filter(lambda coords: all([0 <= coord <= 10 for coord in coords]), zip(x, y))
)
```

If you want to split the `x` and `y` coordinates:

```py
filtered_x, filtered_y = [[c[i] for c in filtered_coords] for i in range(2)]

print(filtered_x) # [5, 3]
print(filtered_y) # [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same index to point to both arrays at the same time.

```
x = [5, -6, 3, 11, -4, 2]
y = [1, 9, 2, 8, 12, -5]
new_x = []
new_y = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    if 0 <= x[i] <= 10 and 0 <= y[i] <= 10:
        new_x.append(x[i])
        new_y.append(y[i])

print(new_x, new_y)
# [5, 3] [1, 2]
```